# LinkList for beginner

Tags: linked-list, singly-linked-list

```
public class Node {

    int item;
    Node next;

    public Node() {

    item = 0;
    this.next = null;

    }
    public Node(int c) {

        item = c;
        next = null;

    }
    public Node(int c, Node next) {

    item = c;
    this.next = next;

    }

    }

public class List {

    Node head;
    Node tail;
    int size;

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return head == null;
    }

    public int size(){
        return size;
    }

    public void addF(int i){

        head = new Node(i, head);
        size++;
    }

    public void addE(int i){

        if(head == null){

            Node s = new Node(i);
            tail = head;
        }else{

            Node s = head;
            while(s.next != null){
                s = s.next;
            }
            s.next = new Node(i);
            size++;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        List l = new List();
        l.addF(55);
        l.addF(56);
        l.addF(57);
        l.addE(54);
        l.addE(53);
        System.out.println(l.toString());
    }

     public String toString() {

         String result = "[  ";

         Node current = head;

         while (current != null) {

         result = result + current.item + "  ";

         current = current.next;
                }
                return result + "]";
              }
}
```

Can anyone explain how the method addE() about else statement in detail for me please? I understand if statement but not else. I'm trying to understand it better. Thank you!!!

Comment: Based on what you currently have, I don't see the point of maintaining a `tail` pointer if you plan to walk the list from the head when inserting a new `Node` at the end.  Please clarify your question, because as it stands now I don't think you can get an exact answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen From what I can see in the code, `tail` isn't even updated anywhere. It's probably just an artifact from some other code.

Comment: @lc. What I'm saying is this: Before we attempt an answer, we need to know what the code itself is trying to do.  As it stands now, this question is actually demanding a refactor _and_ an explanation of what that code does.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Definitely (and the reason I upvoted your comment). Sorry if my comment was confusing; I was just pointing out an additional observation.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That code actually give the answer after I compiled it. The adding front and end method work. I can't see the logic why the code works like that.

Comment: @lc. It is difficult for me to know which one is the old tail or the new tail.

Comment: d.next = new Node(i); 

I think new Node(i) is a new node. d.next is old tail.next. d.next point to new node. please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think the code should be as follows:-

```
public void addE(int i){

        if(head == null){

            Node s = new Node(i);
          head=s; //If the link list is empty then the first element(node) is the head
        }else{


            while(s.next != null){ //Traverse the entire linked list until you raech the tail
                s = s.next;
            }
            s.next = new Node(i);//add the new node
            size++;
        }
    }
```